# Struggling to parse a specific sentence

Tags: particle-に, parsing

From a Bunpro grammar exercise regarding the "-がち" grammar point.

それは初心者にありがちのミスですね。

The given translation is:
"That is a mistake beginners tend to make."

If the sentence were:

それは初心者のミスですね。i.e. "That is a beginner's mistake.", that makes perfect sense to me. But the addition of the にありがち after the 初心者 really throws me off. Bunpro just taught me that the "-がち" mean "to be prone to", "to tend to", so if I were to very literally translate the original it would be:

"That, mistake of tends to exist for beginner, is."

Is that the correct way of thinking about it? Is the に really indicating something like "for"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

がち indicates a tendency.  So, ありがち suggests a tendency for the existence of something.  So, ありがちのミス means a "mistake that has a tendency to be made".  に is often used in this manner to show the locus of what's being talked about.

You could translate this as "for", but approaching it this way will eventually catch you up.  Just learn to recognize this usage for what it is and not try to translate it literally.

The first translation you gave, "This is a mistake which beginners tend to make" is correct.

Comment: So you're suggesting that the に here is the simple "location marking" role? i.e. "mistake that has a tendency to exist *in* beginners"?

Comment: @Valevalorin Kind of.  We don't say things this way in natural English.  But this sort of construction is linguistically present in a lot of languages.  The に here is not being used locatively.  It is more akin to its use when showing the agent of an action (though there is no agent here because there is no action, just a tendency).  I would just recommend making a mental note of this grammatical pattern and not try to create an English equivalent.  As I said in my answer, such an approach will ultimately hinder you in learning Japanese.

Comment: Interpreting the に as "by" (like in the case of a doer of an action) was an approach I thought of when trying to parse this, but given that there wasn't a passive verb I figured that that couldn't be correct, but it seems that maybe that is the more appropriate way of thinking about it.

Comment: There's little to no point in trying to come up with English preposition equivalents to Japanese particles, or to prepositions in other European languages for that matter. In my experience, this is one of the messiest and most exception-riddled areas of any natural language (and English is especially bad here).

Comment: I see no problem in translating に as 'in': 'apt to be found in a beginner'.

Comment: @N.Hunt I didn't say it was wrong.  I did emphasize that trying to force some kind of a word for word translation from Japanese to English will only hinder learning Japanese.

Comment: @N.Hunt Also, there is no word in the Japanese for "found".  The verbal construction is ありがち which just means "tendency to be".  So, if someone who is learning Japanese is trying to translate to English (for whatever reason),  they should try to nevertheless be faithful to the general semantics of the sentences.  But particles in Japanese have no clear one-to-one correspondence to English and I recommend just learning how they are naturally and idiomatically used in Japanese.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think you will find that 'to be found' is a not infrequent translation of ある, for example, from 斎藤和英大辞典: いくらでもある They are to be found in any number.

Comment: @N.Hunt Interesting point.  Thank you for sharing that.